# Using MongoDB for multi-tenant applications

Tags: database, mongodb

How can you use MongoDB in a multi-tenant environment? By multi-tenant I mean, one MongoDB instance used by multiple organizational apps.

As such, we can have App A, App B, and App C use the same MongoDB instance with each application isolated from here other, meaning, for example, a "User" Collection for App A cannot be accessed by App B and vice-versa.

There seems to be no concept of "Namespace" with MongoDB that can be used to assign for each application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have role based access control, and can control which user is allowed to do what on each resource.

From your question, it looks like you are interested in collection level control. Please refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/#collection-level-access-control). Please make sure you are looking at the right version for MongoDB.

So you will end up with different credentials per tenant.

Caveat; you can't throttle noisy neighbours in this design.

> For example, a user defined role can contain the following privileges:
>
> ```
> privileges: [
>   { resource: { db: "products", collection: "inventory" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert" ] },
>   { resource: { db: "products", collection: "orders" },  actions: [ "find" ] }
> ]
> ```

Another option is to create separate database per tenant. But that increases your management (CI/CD/DevOps) costs. For eg. a change in an index will have to be applied per tenant. And you will need to make sure that change is applied correctly.

It depends on how many tenants. For a small number it is ok.

For large number, would be better to be pure SaaS based, and have tenantId as part of every document you store, retrieve, delete etc.

Comment: Actually, in my case, each application can have any or both (from your example) --- both "inventory" and "orders" collection, and will both write and read into it. I'm looking not at creating a database for each programmatically.

Comment: @quarks just added some more details to the answer

Comment: What do mean by "pure SaaS based"?

Comment: Software-as-a-Service, providing multiple tenants the access to your app. Hence keeping all of them in one database (separated by tenantId)